# SQL + Cumulative Count and Sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table name as WO which shows when a Work Order (WOPK) has been requested and when it has been completed.if value for complete value is null, it means that it has not been completed.

```
WOPK        Requested  Complete
----------- ---------- ----------
1111        2014-12-11 NULL
2222        2014-12-11 2014-12-11
3333        2014-12-11 2014-12-12
4444        2014-12-12 2014-12-12
5555        2014-12-12 NULL
6666        2014-12-13 NULL
```

I want to calculate the cumulative count of work orders not completed every calendar day, from the same day or from days before that.

desired result :

```
Requested         Count of Not Complete Work Orders (cumulative)
-----------      -----------------------------------------------
2014-12-11             2
2014-12-12             2
2014-12-13             3
```

Please advise. 
Ali Nazarian

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: SQL Server is the database that I am using.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a correlated subquery:

```
select wo.*,
       (select count(*)
        from wo wo2
        where wo2.requested <= wo.requested and
              wo2.complete is null
       ) as RunningNotCompleted
from wo;
```

This is standard SQL and should work in almost any database, including the ones you have tagged.

EDIT:

If you just want this by day, then use `group by`:

```
select requested,
       (select count(*)
        from wo wo2
        where wo2.requested <= wodate.requested and
              wo2.complete is null
       ) as RunningNotCompleted
from (select wo.requested, count(*) as cnt
      from wo
      group by wo.requested
     ) wodate;
```

I note that this is standard SQL and will run in any database.  However, there are other methods specific to both SQL Server and MySQL.

Comment: your answer does not work  for the first date as you could see on the first date 2014-12-11 shows 1 one work order as not completed but as you could see from the table , on 2014-12-11 , there were 2 work orders not completed.

Comment: what is your idea about this ?

Comment: select wo.*,
       (select count(*)
        from wo wo2
        where wo2.requested <= wo.requested and (wo2.complete is null or wo.Requested<wo2.complete) 
       ) as RunningNotCompleted
from wo
order by wo.Requested;